# Table View cells overwriting data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two different kind of cell layouts in my `tableView`.One for normal height and other for expanded height.Both of them are made in XIB.The problem is that the expanded cell is overwriting data.(For example the labels are set with some text which keeps on adding on top of previous text as I go on expanding different cells).

Here's how the cells are loaded.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *expandedCellIdentifier = @"ExpandedCell";
    if (!isExpanded)
    {
        ListCell *cell =(ListCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil)
        {
            NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ListCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = nibs[0];
        }
        cell.Name.text = [[bArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Name"];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        expCell =(ExpandedCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:expandedCellIdentifier];
        if (expCell==nil)
        {
            NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ExpandedCell" owner:self options:nil];
            expCell = nibs[0];
        }
        UILabel *jTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 6, 72, 10)];
        jTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeRequired];
        [expCell.background_View addSubview:jTime];

        return expCell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label gets added every time when the cell is reused. Use this code in `else` part of your `if` condition to avoid that:

```
expCell = (ExpandedCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:expandedCellIdentifier];
if (expCell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ExpandedCell" owner:self options:nil];
    expCell = nibs[0];
    UILabel *jTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 6, 72, 10)];
    [jTime setTag:100]; //or any value
    [expCell.background_View addSubview:jTime];
}
UILabel *jTimeLabel = (UILabel *)[expCell.background_View viewWithTag:100];
jTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeRequired];

return expCell;
```

Through this code, your label will get added only once.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding new subview to your `expcell` every time it's dequeued.

Comment: If you are loading cell from nib, why don't you put your subview there, to start with?

Comment: There is some drawing stuff also which I need to do programatically.Thats why using things this way.

Comment: Well, if you absolutely have to add subview that way, add it only when cell is loaded from nib.

Answer (score 0):

Because of these lines:

```
UILabel *jTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 6, 72, 10)];
jTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeRequired];
[expCell.background_View addSubview:jTime];
```

That will add new UILabel everytime the cell is reused.